# Would it be necessary to have UK visa?

Tags: schengen, transit, indian-citizens, lhr

We are all Indian passport holders. We plan to travel in 2 groups to Vienna from Mumbai.

The first group goes BOM-LHR-JFK-LHR-Vienna-LHR-BOM. Everybody in this group will have valid visas for USA & Schengen. Would it be necessary to have UK visa?

The second group goes BOM-LHR-Vienna-LHR-BOM. Everybody in this group will have valid visas for Schengen. Would it be necessary to have UK visa?

Comment: Short answer is, I believe, yes -- but the linked question will confirm. Basically if you change in Heathrow you *will* go through passport control and I'm pretty sure Indian passport holders need a transit visa (not necessarily a full entry visa).

Comment: @SpaceDog: Heathrow does have direct airside transit, which doesn't pass through passport control. However, Indian nationals nevertheless need direct airside transit visas, unless one of the exemptions apply to them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Really, I may be mis-remembering but I thought you got funneled through security, passport and customs on any change in LHR. Maybe the passport bit isn't full passport control but a visa check. I acknowledge you don't have to go landside on a change but I'm still sure I had my passport checked the last few times I did it. I'll happily admit I could be wrong, I'm generally not paying that much attention and I avoid changing at LHR if I possibly can.